# Another way to say "I identify as"

Tags: phrase-requests, sexual-minorities

I was hoping this group of educated people could help me find another phrase for "I identify as". Ideally I'm looking for a phrase to replace this one that's used in the transgender community. Personally, I am a cis woman who just wants to word things another way. Bing GPT wasn't very helpful:

- I see myself as
- I consider myself to be
- I view myself as
- I regard myself as
- I define myself as
- I describe myself as
- I label myself as
- I categorize myself as
- I classify myself as
- I perceive myself as

These just don't have the right ooomf or meaning.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why wouldn't _I am a..._ work? If you could add details to explain what exactly you're looking for, and why the classic _I identify as..._ doesn't work, it would be helpful.

Comment: Why don't they have the right "ooomf"? What "ooomf" are you looking for?

Comment: We can't answer questions about "ooomf" but we can about meaning. What meaning do you want? Why?

Comment: Your insights are helpful,, thank you. A little more clarification, if you don't mind. In no way am I trying to take away from the trans community by making fun of or belittling the phrase that they have taken over "I identify as...". However I've seen bumper stickers that say "I identify as a racecar" and find it very funny! Or a tshirt that says "I identify as a toaster" and thought that was a hoot. The rainbow is now symbolic of the gay community (and reading rainbow). And it seems that the phrase "I identify as" is now part of the Trans community. This is why I'm searching.

Comment: Plus, I don't want to rip off any community but am looking for phrase to put on a tshirt.

Comment: @StuartF, ooomf, or rather oomph, can be a part of the term's meaning, or sufficiently related to the term's usage, to be within the scope of this site. It is true, though, that one would need to know more about the kind of oomph that is sought, and for that it might be helpful if the OP explained why she thinks that the listed terms lack it.

Comment: @sundawning So just to clarify: are you looking for a way to say "I identify as a toaster" that doesn't potentially appear to be mocking trans people? If so, that should be in your question.

Answer (score 1):

> These just don't have the right ooomf or meaning.

Your question contains your answer:

> Personally, I am a cis woman...

The simplest, clearest, most direct and concise way of saying this is *I am.*

Consider what the other phrases imply:

*I consider...* and the like leave open the possibility that others disagree with you.  But what right have others to define you? Don't allow them to weaken your sense of self.  *I am...* is all you need.

*I define...* is furthermore redundant.  Saying *I am X* defines you.  Adding *I define* doesn't change that, but it does still call attention to the possibility that others may disagree.

Short, simple, concise, direct: *I am* is fine all by itself.

Comment: *I am* can work in some contexts, but *I identify as* carries some implications that *I am* does not, and it seems that the OP wishes to capture these implications.

Answer (score 0):

Given the 10 alternatives you suggest, it's a bit hard to understand how to capture the "oomf" you're looking for. However, a variation of your proposed

> I define myself as ...

is

> I am defined by ...

or

> I am defined as ...

This has the "oomf" that it purports to be a statement of objective fact, rather than your interpretation. The latter two place imply a third-party definition, rather than a first-person one. Again, "oomf" here could use clarification.

Comment: _I am defined as_ really doesn't work, though. It implies that others are foisting the pronouns upon the OP.

Comment: Exactly, yes. The "oomf" is third party. Removes the first person opinion, and dissociates any interest.

Comment: Your insights are helpful,, thank you. A little more clarification, if you don't mind. In no way am I trying to take away from the trans community by making fun of or belittling the phrase that they have taken over "I identify as...". However I've seen bumper stickers that say "I identify as a racecar" and find it very funny! Or a tshirt that says "I identify as a toaster" and thought that was a hoot. 

The rainbow is now symbolic of the gay community (and reading rainbow). And it seems that the phrase "I identify as" is now part of the Trans community. This is why I'm searching.

Answer (score 0):

One formula that many trans people use (IME) is to introduce themself by name, then state their pronoun. For example "I'm Alex, he/him" or "I'm Robin, they/them".

Comment: Considering that this answer is a report of truth gained from experience, rather than an expression of opinion, please could the downvoter explain their DV?

Answer (score -1):

Do it like Helen Reddy . . .

1. Start with *I am*.
2. Add your noun identity.
3. Delete any articles (e.g. *a*).

. . . [I Am Woman](https://youtu.be/rptW7zOPX2E?si=5ykrD74OX9tBuNnm)

<sub>See also: [Wikipedia—I Am Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_Woman)</sub>

Comment: This works as a song lyric. If you try to use it in conversation you sound like Tarzan.

Comment: @Barmar — The idea is to subvert the “label” by turning it into an adjective. *I am strong. I am invincible. I am woman.* Surely *I am male* does not sound like Tarzan to you. *I am cisgender.* *I am genderqueer.* etc.

Comment: They don't sound weird because they already *are* adjectives. To use a noun after "I am", we normally add an article: "I am a woman" or "I am the President". Tarzanish involves leaving out verbs ("You Jane") and articles, and incorrect conjugation ("**Me** Tarzan")

Comment: @Barmar The most obvious scenario for when you can use a noun without any article after *be* is when it's construed to be a position or rank. *I am President. I am King. I am Captain. I am Headmaster.*  Those may read somewhat better if followed by something limiting or explaining where that rank applies, like *here* or *for life* or *pro tem*  or *of this school* or *of the swim team* or *of this life raft* or *of the hill*.